# PHP for loop gives error(internal server error) when run more than 160 times

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, internal-server-error

I have an array with around 300 or 400 elements.  I am using a `foreach` loop to process every array element, like this:

```
$cnt=0;
foreach($resIds as $resId)
{
  $cnt++;
  //my queries and other code 

}
```

My problem is that the above code causes an internal server error.

If I put one condition in the loop it's working fine for first 160 loops, like:

```
$cnt=0;
    foreach($resIds as $resId)
    {
      $cnt++;
      if($cnt<=160)
      {
        //my queries and other code 
      }

    }
```

If I set `$cnt` variable to 161 it will give error of **Internal Server Error**.

Can anyone help me with this?

here is the Code

```
foreach($resIds as $resId)
 {

$cnt++;
if($cnt<=160)
{
    $transRes = $conn->query('select * from bb_users where id = '.$resId.' and deleted=0');
    while($trans = $transRes->fetch())
    {
    $user = $cartObj->getUserInfo($trans['Session_Id']);

$cartRes = $conn->query('select * from bb_cart where Session_Id = "'.$user['Session_Id'].'" and deleted=0');
$cartdetail = '';
$finaltotal = '';
$productregisterRes = $conn->query("Select * from product_register where OrderId = '".$user['OrderId']."'")->fetch();   

while($cart = $cartRes->fetch())
{
    $ProductId = $cart['ProductId'];
    $ProductName = $cart['ProductName'];
    if($cart['Color']!="")
    {
        $freeproductname = stripslashes($productregisterRes['FREEProductName']);            
        $freeproductname = str_replace(",Lady Gaga featuring (Born This Way & Bad Romance)", "", $freeproductname);
        $ProductColor = '['.$cart['Color'].']';
    }
    else
    {
        $freeproductname ="";
        $ProductColor ="";
    }
    $ProductQty = $cart['ProductQty'];
    $ProductPrice = $cartObj->getpriceformat($cart['ProductPrice']);                
    $Discount = $cartObj->getpriceformat($cart['Discount']);        
    $TotalPrice = $cartObj->getpriceformat($cart['TotalPrice']);
    $finaltotal += $cart['TotalPrice'];

    $cartdetail .='<tr>
        <td align="left" width="40%">'.stripdata($ProductName).'<br/><I>'.$freeproductname.'<br/>'.$ProductColor.'</I></td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">$'.$ProductPrice.'</td>

        <td align="center" width="15%">'.$ProductQty.'</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">$'.$Discount.'</td>
        <td align="right" width="15%" style="padding-right:45px">$'.$TotalPrice.'</td>
      </tr>';
}
$VoucherCode=$crypt->decrypt($user['mpcode']);
$State = getStateName($user['State']);
$Country = getCountryName($user['Country']);

$billingname = stripdata($user['FirstName']).' '.stripdata($user['LastName']);
$billingaddress = stripdata($user['Address1']).'<br>'.stripdata($user['City']).', '.$State.' '.stripdata($user['Zip']).'<br>'.$Country;

$ShippingState = getStateName($user['ShippingState']);
$ShippingCountry = getCountryName($user['ShippingCountry']);

$shippingname = stripdata($user['ShippingFirstName']).' '.stripdata($user['ShippingLastName']);
$shippingaddress = stripdata($user['ShippingAddress1']).'<br>'.stripdata($user['ShippingCity']).', '.$ShippingState.' '.stripdata($user['ShippingZip']).'<br>'.$ShippingCountry;

$email = $user['Email'];
$phone = $user['Phone'];
$DateTime = getDateTime($user['DateTime']);
$afterdiscount = $cartObj->getpriceformat($finaltotal) - ($cartObj->getpriceformat($user['mpcode_discount']) + $cartObj->getpriceformat($user['misc_discount']));   
$misc_discount = $cartObj->getpriceformat($user['misc_discount']);
```

}
}

Comment: Look at your server logs to see what the error is (probably a timeout of script execution).

Comment: Well as the problem is likely to be somewhere in your `my queries and other code`, it's going to be very difficult for anybody but yourself to answer as we can't see any of that code

Comment: `my queries and other code` makes this Internal Server Error

Comment: Whats in `my queries and other code?`

Comment: Further, what's contained in your array? In particular, what's _actually_ contained in the 161st element of your array (as opposed to what you _think_ is there)?

Comment: in "my query and code"  i am firing queries according to array value

Comment: whatever it is at the 161st element but it gives error

Comment: code in side loop is too big is it ok to post it here ?

Comment: i have posted code above

Answer (score 0):

On most servers the timeout is set pretty low for "scripts running" which includes php pages.  error 500 can indicate it took too long to complete all the iterations and 160 probably hits your timeout.